# JQuery next selector or something similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html code like

```
 <ul>
    <li>Some Name <a class="rud" href="#">remove</a><input type="text" value="one" readonly="readonly" name="array" /></li>
     <li>Some other name <a class="rud" href="#">remove</a><input type="text" value="two" readonly="readonly" name="array" /></li>
</ul>
```

I want when i click on `<a>` to rename input name and  value.

Result should be

```
<li>Some Name <a class="rud" href="#">undo</a><input type="text" value="one" readonly="readonly" name="deleted" /></li>
```

Jquery on document ready click event

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rud").click(function() {
           // alert(this).next().val();
           // get input button in this <li></li>.
           // change name
           $(this).text("undo");



        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".rud").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .text("undo")  // change link text
        .next(':input') // go to nex input
        .attr('name','deleted'); // chage name attr 
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XAYvV/4/)**

Comment: There's none, I upvoted the answer. I'll delete the comments.

Comment: if your question is what i did 30 sec ago, then NO :)